# How to get View/Widget from getItemAtPostion method, android?

Tags: android, gallery

How to use gallery.getItemAtPosition(position)
to get the view object like below.

```
Object obj = gallery.getItemAtPosition(position);
View v = (View)object;
ImageView imgview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageId);
```

But if i use like that it is giving class cast exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I use it like this, on select event

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View v, int position,
            long arg3) {
        //here v is the imageview which is selected.
                //In your case u might want something like this.
                ImageView img = (ImageView) arg0.getChildAt(position); //To get the view
}
```

Comment: what is the error , or why it is not working ? Above code is just a snippet !

Comment: use gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); and implement onItemSelectedListener in Activity class

Answer (score 0):

That source code does not make much sense, or vital information is missing.
Have you connected a SpinnerAdapter to the gallery? What type of objects do the adapter return?

I assume all objects in the gallery are of the same type?

```
Object obj = gallery.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

You should cast to this object type directly.

```
TheType obj = (TheType)gallery.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: Iam using baseadapter and for each row I have created another layout in that i declared Imageview for each row of gallery.Please , just change the above code in working condition.Iam not able to understane TheType means View or ImageView.

Comment: I used like this ImageView imgView = (ImageView)gallery.getItemAtPosition(position);Same Java.lang.ClassCastException.